# Two CSS files linked, only one is being used, other is ignored

Tags: css

When loading two CSS files via an include I am only seeing one of them being used. The other isn't being included and I don't know why.

I have a standard header file which is included on all of the site's pages.

Example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

This is of course a cut down version of the header for simplification. As you can see both CSS files are within the css directory. but only the main CSS file is being recognised.

Comment: Have you tried removing main.css from the header and checked if the second one recognised? Also how about swapping the order, moving main.css afer the jquery-ui.css? I am unable to find any issue with the code that you have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either one of the CSS files cannot be loaded (probably because of a typo or a server misconfiguration). You can detect that by checking that all resources are properly loaded in the developer tools of your browser.

The other cause may be that you're implicitly expecting your own stylesheets to take precedence over the default jQuery UI ones. If that's the case, move your own stylesheets under the jQuery UI one, or make your rules more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than the default ones.

[This is a simple demo that shows that your example works](http://phihag.de/2011/so/2css.html).

**Solution:**

In your live example, you're missing `rel=stylesheet` for the jQuery UI stylesheet:

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

should be

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I have moved my css to be after the jquery-ui css and this has the same effect, thanks for trying though

Comment: @Deviland Then how does your example differ from my demo page? How are you determining that there is no effect? (This would be a lot easier if you could provide a demonstration page)

Comment: sorry did not mean to just post link, this is the actual page

Comment: @Deviland Both CSS stylesheets load fine, but the jQuery UI one has no effect, since it only applies styles to element with class `ui-something`, and you don't have any elements with any of these classes on your page.

Comment: hi Phihag the Jquery adds these class dynamically as the page loads within the javascript you will see a $('#tabs').tabs();

Comment: @Deviland My bad, didn't have JavaScript activated. Updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: what a noob error i can only assume that the similar lengths of the stylesheet declarations made me think they were complete thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the rel attribute in the first link tag, and most likely this is the reason it's not being parsed as CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to close you link tags, just add a forward slash '/' before the closing of both tags.

Comment: yes sorry the example does not have the slashes but the real code does thanks for pinting this out I will update my example :)

Comment: Well then the only other thing it could be is maybe you've spelt your file names incorrectly - if you have the absolute paths, try visiting them in your browser and see if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

You're certain the second file is linked correctly? Check Firebug's NET panel, for instance, to double-check that it's loading and not returning a 404 error or somesuch.

You wouldn't be the first developer to be brought down by an unintentional typo!

Comment: i have checked with firebug and all css loads, which is confusing me lol

Comment: Sorry to explain that last comment further i can click on the css link in view source and the css loads, but in the NET panel it is not shown as being loaded